# why wkhtmltopdf doesn't work with php

Tags: php, wkhtmltopdf

I ran the codes:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL); 
ini_set( 'display_errors','1');

$d = 'usr/bin/wkhtmltopdf /www/11_07_13/task1/ml.html hd.pdf';

    //also used: $d = 'xvfb-run -a wkhtmltopdf ml.html hd.pdf';
               //$d = 'xvfb-run -a usr/bin/wkhtmltopdf ml.html hd.pdf';

if (exec($d)) {
    echo "success";
}
else{
    echo "error";
}
```

and everytime it shows error.

At first I installed wkhtmltopdf via terminal, dinn't work. Then I downloaded the file: wkhtmltopdf-0.11.0_rc1-static-i386.tar.bz2' from the code.google... site, unzipped and placed it in my www/test folder to use with php; with no luck.

but the command 'wkhtmltopdf test.html test.pdf' from terminal woks just fine.

Then where is the problem???

Can anyone please help me out???
p.s. I use ubuntu 12.04. php 5.4.7

The error message from exec call shows: Array ( [0] => /usr/bin/wkhtmltopdf: /opt/lampp/lib/libgcc_s.so.1: version `GCC_4.2.0' not found (required by /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6) )

Comment: `and everytime it shows error` - you should read the error message from the exec call - exec has [more parameters](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php). There's an obvious error in the command being executed which will probably be obvious to you _if you read the output from exec_. (-1 for not including a relevant error message in the question - who upvoted this???).

Comment: When I said, "and everytime it shows error" I did mean: echo "error".  did you notice the last part of my codes?: else{ echo "error";} I did mean this word 'error'; not exactly any error message. And when I discard if...else part and run exec($d); it returns a big-white-blank-page. anyway thanks...

Comment: and when I said `you should read the error message from the exec call` I meant you should do exactly that. Knowing that the code enters `echo "error"` does not say anything useful, whereas `if you read the output from exec` - it would be.

Comment: The error message shows: Array ( [0] => /usr/bin/wkhtmltopdf: /opt/lampp/lib/libgcc_s.so.1: version `GCC_4.2.0' not found (required by /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6) )

Comment: You now have an error message to follow up with - in the question the path to wkhtmltopdf is not that

Comment: Actual version of GCC is .. ? `gcc --version`, `man gcc` http://linux.die.net/man/1/gcc